# All Transaction Emails Getting Sent Only from 'postmaster@example.com'

Tags: magento2, sales, smtp

In spite of configuring all the Sales Email to a particular ID, example sales@example.com, all the Sales related emails are being sent from **postmaster@example.com**

Comment: Can you please add more informations about your question, what you did and what you want to to

Comment: This issue cropped up after I updated Magento from 2.2.3 to 2.2.5. The fix provided by Ryan Hoerr has resolved the issue. Since I didn't require the Amazon modules, I disabled them and now my Sales Email are working normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Magento 2.2.4 or 2.2.5, there is a known bug where the Amazon integration modules break the email from address.

Github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

If this is your problem, you can choose one of several ways to fix it:

1. Apply official Magento patch MDVA-10993, as detailed and provided here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952#issuecomment-414976952
2. Install community module `sashas777/bug-from-email`: https://github.com/sashas777/bug-from-email
3. Disable the Amazon modules by running this command from SSH: `php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Payment Amazon_Login`